# How to pipe stdin from child to parent?

Tags: c, pipe, stdin

I'm trying to `exec()`a child process from a parent process. In this child process, I ask the user to enter a message so it can be printed out by the parent process but I can't find a way to do it...

So far, my code is :

**parent.c**

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int fd[2];
    char line[80];

    pipe(fd);

    pid_t pid = (pid_t)fork();

    if(pid > 0) {
        waitpid(pid, NULL, 0);
        close(fd[0]);
        int size = read(fd[1], line, 79);
        close(fd[1]);
        line[size] = '\0';
        printf("[parent] Received \"%s\", size = %d\n", line, size);
    }
    else {
        close(fd[1]);
        close(stdin);
        dup2(fd[0], stdin);
        close(fd[0]);
        exec("./child", 0, NULL);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**child.c**

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char line[80];

    printf("[child] Enter message: ");
    gets(line, 80);
    printf("[child] line = %s\n", line);

    return 0;
}
```

When I launch the parent process, it displays `[child] Enter message:` but when I try to type something, nothing appears, even if I hit the return key.

Do you know how can I make it work ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: In the parent, don't wait for the child to finish before you read from the pipe. It might work in this case because you probably don't write enough to fill the pipes buffer, but if it is filled then the writer will block and you have a deadlock.

Comment: Also, what version of the `gets` function do you have that take a buffer size? Are you using some variant of `gets_s`?

Comment: There are also some other problems with your parent program. Like for example it should not compile cleanly.

Comment: I'm coding the user space of [nachOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_Another_Completely_Heuristic_Operating_System) so the only version of `gets` I have is `gets(char* s, int maxlength)`.

Comment: Whoa!  That's a highly non-standard interface to `gets()`.  (A far better interface, but completely non-standard and therefore completely confusing.)  That complicates life — are any of the other standard-looking functions the same as the actual standard functions?  How can we guess the behaviour of all the other functions that look as if they might be POSIX functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a workaround. My actual goal was to pass information between parent and child. My error was to `dup2` on `stdin`. By doing this, I couldn't enter anything when the program asked. So I passed the value of the file descriptors in the `argv` and my problem was solved.

Thanks again for your help !

Answer (score 1):

Besides the problems mentioned in my comments, the problem you are experiencing is a *deadlock*. You get that because the parent process waits for the child process to exit. But the child process is waiting for input that never arrives.

That's because in the child process you say that the input should come from the *pipe*.

Furthermore in the parent process you attempt to *read* from the write-end of the pipe.

Finally, your program will never work as long as the child process is wanting to read user-input, because all user-input will go to the *parent* process.

To make it all work, you need to rethink your design, and to make the *parent* process the one that reads input from the user, and writes to the pipe. And the child process should read from the pipe and print to (the non-piped) standard output. Or you close the (normal, non-piped) standard input in the parent, and in the child you write to the pipe (as standard output).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately, I can't rethink the design since I'm asked to do it as I explained. But maybe my approach isn't good and I have to rethink that. I'll keep you updated!

Answer (score 0):

Your code has several problems:

- you mix integer (low level) file descriptors, and (high level) FILE * constants.
- you invert stdin and stdout as well as the order of the descriptors obtained through `pipe`
- you write a message on stdout when you intend to redirect it (should use stderr)

Here is a fixed version (I changed your gets by fgets, as well as your exec with execl to have everything to compile):

parent.c:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int fd[2];
    char line[80];

    pipe(fd);

    pid_t pid = (pid_t)fork();

    if(pid > 0) {
        waitpid(pid, NULL, 0);
        close(fd[1]);
        int size = read(fd[0], line, 79);
        close(fd[0]);
        line[size] = '\0';
        printf("[parent] Received \"%s\", size = %d\n", line, size);
    }
    else {
        close(fd[0]);
        close(1);
        dup2(fd[1], 1);
        close(fd[1]);
        execl("./child", NULL);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

child.c

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char line[80];

    fprintf(stderr, "[child] Enter message: ");
    fgets(line, 80, stdin);
    printf("[child] line = %s\n", line);

    return 0;
}
```